# How to give google places api a place as string and have it return an array of places?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I simply want to give google places a string and get a list of places in return 
I don't want to use autocomplete fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after intializing the places API using this function

```
  private fun initPlaces() {
    Places.initialize(context!!, getString(R.string.placesApiKey))
    placesClient = Places.createClient(context!!)
    autocompleteSessionToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()

}
```

You can simply send your query string after getting it from edittext or whatever to getSuggestion function

```
private fun getSuggestions(query: String) {
    var findAutocompletePredictionsRequest=FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest
            .builder()
            .setSessionToken(autocompleteSessionToken)
            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
            .setQuery(query)
            .build()         placesClient!!.findAutocompletePredictions(findAutocompletePredictionsRequest).addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener {
          if(it.isSuccessful){
              Log.d(TAG, "getSuggestions: -----------------------SUCCESS")
              var predictionsResponse=it.result
              predictionList=predictionsResponse!!.autocompletePredictions
              createList()


          }
          }
      })

}
```

after that you can use the returned list to populate a recyclerview or whatever you want

```
private fun createList() {
    var suggestionsStringArray =Array<String>(predictionList!!.size){""}
    if(predictionList!!.isNotEmpty()){
        for (i in predictionList!!.indices){
            suggestionsStringArray[i] = predictionList!![i].getFullText(null).toString()
        }
        populateAdapter(suggestionsStringArray)
    }
}
```